# Reducing Updates Load on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My Application is continue on updating various records with each request suppose 4/3 if per request 4 are selects 3 update queries are then performed.

These are simple updates just for logging suppose to count requests coming from each person etc like `field` = `field` + 1 Or - 1 Or time() etc

Please suggest the best way to reduce this load, I'm thinking to store these updates for some time in a text file & then flush it to database it once so to reduce number of queries.

Am I correct in my approach?
Are simple text files safer for this kind of work?
What should I do? 
Database temp table also removed upon script execution.

Comment: [Read this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/07/01/implementing-efficient-counters-with-mysql/) at MySQL performance blog

Comment: Are you sure text-files would be that much faster? With suitable database schema, you could work in RAM alone, for example. Also, let's not forget the words of Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Yes, thank you. I tried memory engine & that's just awesome.I think it will resolve my issues.
But still mysql is bad as it can distribute data on multiple servers by self :(